# Restating The Pigeonhole Principle (Strong Form)

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, logic, set-theory, pigeonhole-principle

I'm quite familiar with the pigeonhole principle (strong form), namely that principle which says that if $q_1 + q_2 + ... + q_n – n + 1$ objects are distributed (or taken) to (or from) $n$ boxes, then for some $i = 1, 2, ..., n$, it is the case that the $i$th box contains $q_i$ objects (or that $q_i$ objects were taken from the $i$th box. However, for some reason, I've only seen this being stated with boxes; and I believe it could be equivalently restated using actual mathematical objects. This is how I attempted this restatement:

if $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a family, $I = \{1, 2, ..., n\}$ and $\vert \{X_i\}_{i \in I}\vert = q_1 + q_2 + ... + q_n – n + 1$,then $(\exists i \in I)(\exists X_i \in \{X_i\}_{i\in I})(X_i \ge q_i)$

Is this a correct restatement of the fact? I am nothing but new to combinatorics, hence I need approval from those more professional. Moreover, is there a traditional restatement of this principle with mathematical objects? I would be most interested in that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The correct conclusion is that for some $i \in \{1,2,...,n\}$ the $i$th box contains *at least* $q_i$ objects. The restatement is saying the exact same thing.

Comment: I edited my restatement to say $\ge$ (at least) instead of $=$; is it correct now? I'm trying to restate it using mathematical objects instead of boxes.

Comment: If $|\bigcup_{i=1}^nX_i|\gt\sum_{i=1}^n(q_i-1)$ then $|X_i|\ge q_i$ for some $i$.

Comment: Your $|\{X_i\}_{i\in I}|$ is a very weird notation for $|\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i|$.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see the mistake. So if I replace $\vert \{X_i\}_{i \in I}\vert$ with $\vert\bigcup_{i = 1}^nX_i\vert$. Would that be a correct restatement?

Comment: If you have the vertical line "$|$" on your keyboard, you can use it alone for \vert.